# Anonymous access enabled SharePoint site's list items are coming on Google Search, How to restrict it?

Tags: 2010, anonymous-authentication, public-website

I have an HTML website lets say https://www.abcd.com on the same website I have linked our career portal `(www.careers.abcd.com)`, thru which Anonymous user can fill their information and upload their resumes. 
Career portal development has been done on SharePoint 2010.

https://www.abcd.com website is already crawled thru `google search console` so that user can find it on google. But the issue comes when the user searches their names on google, SharePoint list stored career profiles are also coming on google search results from there they can see their complete profile even they can download resumes as well. which violates user privacy.

One more issue I am facing, if the end user has little bit SharePoint knowledge then they can go to the list/libraries thru SharePoint internal links as the user have Anonymous access to the SharePoint 2010 website.